# Ajax cant run function in controller in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have issue with ajax. I have rows of items, each row have delete button. So I can send id of the item to ajax and to controller and make my stuff. My problem is that I can't run the controller's function.

This is my JS - AJAX

```
$(".remove-officer-button").on('click', function (e) {

    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?')) {
        var whichtr = $(this).closest("tr");
        var itemId = '{!! $row->id !!}';
        var token = '{!! csrf_field() !!}';
        whichtr.remove();

        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            dataType: "json",
            url: '{{ route('admin.item.delete', app()->getLocale()) }}',

            data:{
                '_token': token,
                '_method': 'POST',
                'itemId': itemId
            },
            success: function () {
                console.log(data.success)
            }
        });
    }else {
        console.log(data.error)
    }


});
```

My route:

```
 Route::get('/ajax_delete', 'HomeController@ajaxDelete')->name('admin.item.delete');
```

Controller:

```
public function ajaxDelete(Request $request)
{
    dd($request);
    return $this->AOrepository->ajaxDelete($request);
}
```

This is showing browser:
[image: 405 means Method not allowed]
405: Method not allowed

So the result is that the row is deleted by `whichtr.remove();` but that's all. Also I tried only to redirect somewhere in controller but it doesn't work

Please can you help me guys?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Route::get` but in your JavaScript you are doing a `POST` call. You should either change the `Route::get` to be `Route::post` or change the JavaScript to `type: 'Get'`.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to change it back to POST setup. Error in browser changed to 419

Comment: This probably means you need to add the XSRF/CSRF token to the request.

Comment: I've found this. Is it that what I need? 

`$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});`

Anyway I don't know where to put it :D

Comment: I think before the `$.ajax` call

Comment: Should I call it inside the `$.ajax`? Otherwise, nothing changed

Comment: No, before. not in. Did you add `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />` to your HTML page?